# Как исправить данную ошибку?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

При запуске кода выдаётся следующая ошибка:

> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
>   profiles are currently active).

Вот код в pom.xml(Использую postgresql):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.elnur</groupId>
    <artifactId>tritter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DataBase support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

А вот код из applications.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/tritter
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=passwd
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: Дело не в поме, а в `application.properies`

Comment: Скиньте его сюда, где вы прописываете пароль и логин юзеру (пароль и юзера можете сменить на несуществующий для конфиденциальности)

Comment: @Antonio112009 Скинул

Comment: У вас дрова не настроены.

Comment: Рассмотрите пример вот тут — https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAuthenticationExample/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: Дрова для postgresql: org.postgresql.Driver